# Communicating an array of bvec2 between host->shader and/or shader->shader

Tags: glsl, vulkan, compute-shader

I need to communicate two boolean values per entry of an array in a compute shader. For now, I'm getting them from the cpu, but later I will want to generate these values from another compute shader that runs before that one. I got this working as follows:

Using `glm::bvec2` I can place the booleans relatively packed into memory (the bvec stores one bool per byte. could be nicer, but will do for now, I can always manually pack this). Then, I use `vkMapMemory` to place the data into a Vulkan buffer (I then copy it to a device local buffer, but that's probably irrelevant here).

GLSL's bvec2 is not equivalent to that, unfortunately (or at least it won't give me the expected values if I use it, maybe I'm doing it wrong? Using `bvec2 changes[]` yields wrong results in the following code. I suspect an alignment mismatch). Because of that, the compute shader accesses this array as follows:

```c
layout (binding = 2, scalar) buffer Changes
{
    uint changes[];
};

void main() {
    //uint is 4 byte, glm::bvec2 is 2 byte
    uint changeIndex = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x / 2;

    //order seems to be reversed in memory: 
    //v1(x1, y1) followed by v2(x2, y2) is stored as: 0000000(y2) 0000000(x2) 0000000(y1) 0000000(x1) 
    uint changeOffset = (gl_GlobalInvocationID.x % 2) * 16;
    uint maskx = 1 << (changeOffset + 0);
    uint masky = 1 << (changeOffset + 8);

    uint uchange = changes[changeIndex];
    bvec2 change = bvec2(uchange & maskx, uchange & masky);
}
```

This works. Took a bit of trial and error but there we go. I have two questions now:

1. Is there a more elegant way to do this?
2. When generating the values via compute shaders, I would not be using glm::bvec2. Should I perhaps just manually pack the booleans - one per bit - into uints, or is there a better way?

Performance is pretty important to me in this application, as I'm trying to benchmark things. Memory usage optimizations are secondary, but also worth considering. Being relatively inexperienced with optimizing GLSL, I'm happy about any advice you can give me.

Comment: "*Is there a more elegant way to do this?*" What exactly is inelegant here?

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, fair point, I guess... I mean, is there a better data type to choose, can I somehow save myself some of these operations (although I guess bit shifts etc are quite fast), etc. My question was vague because I figured if there is something better, then it's something obvious which I've missed. I suppose packing the booleans bitwise would be possible at pretty much no additional cost. Even the modulo could be done with a bitwise and... Yeah, if there's no obviously better alternative, then I guess this works very well already. I might post my final code as answer, then.

Answer (score 1):

Since `glm::bvec2` stores a boolean as two bytes, perhaps the explicitly 8-bit unsigned integer vector type `u8vec2` provided by the [`GL_EXT_shader_8bit_storage` extension](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/master/extensions/ext/GL_EXT_shader_16bit_storage.txt) would be more convenient here? I don't know if the Vulkan driver you're using will support the necessary feature (I assume it's `storageBuffer8BitAccess`), though.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Andrea mentions a useful extension: `GL_EXT_shader_8bit_storage`.
As the writing access to my booleans is done in parallel, the only option for tight packing is atomics. I've chosen to trade memory efficiency for performance by storing two booleans in one byte, "wasting" 6 bits. The code is as follows:

```c
#extension GL_EXT_shader_8bit_storage : enable

void getBools(in uint data, out bool split, out bool merge) {
    split = (data & 1) > 0;
    merge = (data & 2) > 0;
}

uint setBools(in bool split, in bool merge) {
    uint result = 0;
    if (split) result = result | 1;
    if (merge) result = result | 2;
    return result;
}

//usage:
layout (binding = 4, scalar) buffer ChangesBuffer
{
    uint8_t changes[];
};

//[...]
bool split, merged;
getBools(uint(changes[invocationIdx]), split, merged);
//[...]
changes[idx] = uint8_t(setBools(split, merge));
```

Note the constructors, the data types provided by the extension do not provide any arithmetic operations and must be converted before use.

Comment: You may find that GPU drivers' shader compilers optimise the array nonetheless.

Comment: @Andrea really? I realize SPIRV is an intermediate but In had not expected there to be another set of optimizations in between. That being said, I got the code of the shader from NVIDIA NSight - do I assume incorrectly that that tool extracts the fully compiled shader code and decompiles it?

Comment: SPIR-V is still a lot more high-level than what it compiles to, and using const arrays isn't an uncommon pattern so compilers obviously want to optimise it if they can.

Comment: I don't know anything about NSight, sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately my above solution doesn't work, as I should've known from the start. It leads to race conditions because each uint32 is written to 16 times. if any of those are concurrent, bye bye data. It looks like your 8bit storage extension is the best way to save space, and I've successfully tried that. I should have an update for the answer tomorrow. Thank you for suggesting the extension!

Comment: Glad to help. You could use atomics but actually reducing the size of the accesses is a better idea of course.